# How to say "I don't believe you" in a more academic way?

Tags: formality, politeness, register

How to say "I don't believe you" in a more *academic* way?

I need to say it to my teacher and I do not know how to say it, not to make her mad...

Comment: _Why_ do you need to say it to your teacher? One of my teachers got something wrong once, and I handled it badly. I corrected her in front of the class rather than checking with other authorities that I was in fact right, then informing others who had been mistaught, and then putting it down to human error and moving on.

Comment: If you don't believe your teacher then you should also explain why so? In my opinion, it is good to start like "_I think, this is like this..._" or "_isn't it like this?_".. I prefer first way.

Comment: Have your Dad go down to the school and beat her up.  (A) this is a vague, Miss Manners -type question, (B) Lill has NOT supplied any more info despite a tremendous amount of input and many asking for clarification.

Comment: "With all due respect, you are straining my credulity to the breaking point!"

Comment: The most **academic** way is to say "That's a crock of shit". Most academics talk like real people when they're not in front of an audience. And that's most of the time, thank gods.

Comment: I suggest that the [Academia S.E.](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place to be asking this sort of question, because it is at least as much a matter of academic conduct as it is language, if not more so and the more of the people who visit that website are probably better accustomed to this specific situation than we are.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably avoid saying it directly, as directness is often impolite.

To end an argument, you can suggest that the two of you could "agree to disagree".

If you're looking to discuss a matter further, you can start your comment with,

> "Respectfully, sir/ma'am/professor, ..."

Then follow up with something that is actually respectful of the study and knowledge of your teacher, such as,

> I'm not sure I'm totally convinced. Could you explain further?

OR

> could you show me where I can find that?

Teachers sometimes don't like being challenged, and you can't control your teacher's feelings.  The best course of action in any case would be to take it up with your teacher **one-on-one**, if you can.

Comment: "I'm not sure I'm totally convinced. Could you explain further?" I think this would be most appropriate. Nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

Please can you explain what it is I am misunderstanding here....It looks as if XYZ is the same as ABC, so why are you saying that that is not the case? There must be something I don't understand properly!

Answer (score 4):

In general, you would likely wish to suggest that the error is yours, not theirs.  It's a way of keeping them sympathetic to you.  And, allows both of you to save face.

So, rather than saying you *don't believe them*, you would say that you don't understand their explanation.

Several good ways to do so have been suggested above, to which I will add:

> I'm not sure I see the connection here, could you please explain further?
>   Perhaps you could give another example, I don't understand the one you've given.
>   Can you make this clearer for me? I don't properly follow you.

Then, you can use this tactic to slowly reduce their argument.  As they bring out their points, if you're still not convinced, you will just point out individual points where you are not convinced.

It is a better tactic to address the points individually than as a whole.  If an individual point is in error, you allow them to correct themselves without making them feel as foolish as if you invalidate their entire argument.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean by *I don't believe you*.

If you mean that you think the teacher is lying, then you are probably better advised to talk to a counselor or administrator rather than confront the teacher directly. I can't think of any tactful formulation of your assumption that the teacher is deliberately deceiving you.

If, on the other hand, you are not convinced by an explanation the teacher has given, you could say something like: "*I'm not sure I understand. Could you explain it again please?*" A teacher who gets mad at such a request is in the wrong profession.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you haven't said anything about the nature of the argument.

- Your teacher might be saying that there are just as many real numbers between 0 and 1 as there are between 0 and 2 – in which case your teacher would be right, and your skepticism would be in error.
- Your teacher might be presenting a leading scientific theory as fact, in which case there is room for debate.
- Or, your teacher might just be wrong about something.

No matter which of these three circumstances your situation falls under, how should you voice your skepticism? *Respectfully*.

That said, I'm going to elaborate on Case 2: Your teacher is espousing a popular scientific theory. In this case, a good way to handle the situation is to **not** make this an argument between you and your teacher. *“I don't believe you”* is personal, and therefore confrontational.

Instead, try something more along the lines of:

> There are other respected theories out there – not everyone accepts this as scientific fact.

or:

> I find it interesting how other scientists have proposed competing theories.

or even:

> I know Reynolds has proposed an alternate theory; I think I might be more in his camp.

This allows you to voice your disagreement without directly challenging your teacher, or undermining your teacher's credibility. It's also best to avoid dogmatic language – if it turns out that you are the one in error, you'll have less egg to clean off your face.

Answer (score 0):

In Britain you could preface your counter-argument with the hypocritical  'interesting', e.g.

> "That's a most interesting point of view / argument, but hasn't it been shown / reported that…"

In the USA the meaningless "great" would probably be substituted for "most interesting".